# ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname) ImportError: No module named flask.ext.wtf.TextField

Tags: python, flask

**This is my error message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "app.py", line 9, in
<module>
    from forms import ContactForm   File "/home/wdgzephy/zephy-Web/forms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask.ext.wtf import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField, validators, ValidationError   File
"/home/wdgzephy/zephy-Web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py",
line 87, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname) ImportError: No module named flask.ext.wtf.TextField
```

Can you please help me with this error.  What is my mistake?

Comment: The fields were dropped from Flask-WTF in [version 0.9.0](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/upgrade.html#version-0-9-0).

Answer (score 1):

You have to import wtforms(For flask version 0.9.0 and above):

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form

from wtforms import TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required
```

Comment: Great Answer! And for Flask 0.11 and above change flask.ext.wtf to flask_wtf

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Flask-WTF package installed ?
Which version of Flask you're using ? At the current version, the right import syntax would be:

```
>>> from wtforms import TextField
>>> wtforms.__version__
'2.0.2'
```